# How to get sub folders files or count sub folder files in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to count the sub folder files but its get the below error.

**{"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."}**

```
code :

List list = CContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Lead");
CContext.Load(list);
CContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
CContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
CContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
CContext.ExecuteQuery();
FolderCollection folderCollection = list.RootFolder.Folders;
List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
Console.WriteLine("\nCount total sub folder : " + folderCollection.Count);
if (folderCollection.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Folder folder in folderCollection)
    {
        if (folder.Name == "00111_ACCC74CD7C16VMD11956100224805F1EB")
        {
            CContext.Load(folder.Files);
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();
            FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;
            if (fileCol.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (File file in fileCol.ToArray())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nFile Name : " + file.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```